# Add function in imported package?

Tags: vb.net

I am using a custom controls package in my project, but I would like to add a `OnKeyDown` function to its custom RadioButton.

The thing I'd like to do is skipping the `Keys.Left` and `Keys.Right` inputs if the custom RadioButton has focus:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Left Or Keys.Right Then
        'skip
    Else
        MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `If e.KeyData = Keys.Left OrElse e.KeyData = Keys.Right Then...` is what you need. Do you already have a class that inherits the custom RadioButton? If not, you can just use the `KeyDown` event of the control and do `If e.KeyData = Keys.Left OrElse e.KeyData = Keys.Right Then e.Handled = True`.

Comment: Because I have a lot of RB, I loop through each control and add handlers: `If TypeOf ctl is CustomRadioButton Then AddHandler ctl.KeyDown, AddressOf DisableKeyEvents`. Then in the `DisableKeyEvents`: `If e.KeyData = Keys.Left Or Keys.Right Then DoStuff` but the DoStuff part is not working, the RB still CheckChange between them and I can't figure out why...

Comment: Instead of creating an event handler for all the RBs, you could create a derived class and override the `OnKeyDown` method as you show in the question. Note that the `Keys.Left Or Keys.Right` part is **wrong**. Use the code in my previous comment. If you decided to go with overriding `OnKeyDown`, then `If e.KeyData... Then Exit Sub : MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)` should do the trick. If you go with creating event handlers, then `If e.KeyData... Then e.Handled = True` is the code you need (get the `...` part from my previous comment).

Comment: With that being said, if the sole purpose of disabling the left and right keys for the control is to prevent it from getting checked, you might want to just disable the `AutoCheck` property instead. In that case, you don't have to write any code. However, in that case, clicking the RB will also not cause it to be automatically checked. So, it's up to you to decide which approach is better for your use case.

Comment: But how can I override the custom RB class? I have to create another custom RB class inheriting from it and overriding `OnKeyDown` function right? And so I have to replace the whole project custom RB by the new one?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But you don't need to replace them manually. You can just change the type in the `YourForm.Designer.vb` file. Just replace `OldControlType` with `NewDerivedClassName`. You should be **very careful** while editing the `.Designer.vb` file though. Always have a backup just in case. If you don't like that option, you may go the event handlers route. That works too.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for you answers!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I created a new class inheriting from the custom RadioButton and it works perfectly.

```
Namespace Custom.Controls

    Public Class RadioButton
        Inherits CustomRadioButton

        Protected Overrides Function IsInputKey(keyData As Keys) As Boolean
            If keyData = Keys.Left OrElse
                keyData = Keys.Right Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return MyBase.IsInputKey(keyData)
            End If
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
            If e.KeyData = Keys.Left OrElse
                e.KeyData = Keys.Right Then
                'DoStuff
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```